# TaskFactory().StartNew() finish in order of creation

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am receiving messages via UDP. Messages can arrive *extremely* quickly, i.e every 1ms (but this varies). When a message is received, an event is called:

```
private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, UDPMessage message)
{
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(message);
}
```

As can be seen, the message received is put into a queue to be processed. I do this --and I'm not sure if this is incorrect or not-- to ensure that the UDP receiver thread is free to received the next message (I don't want to block the receive thread and prevent it from receiving a message).

So, when the message is queued, the `MessageQueued` event is raised:

```
private static void MessageQueued(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var processTask = new TaskFactory().StartNew(ProcessMessage);
}
```

`ProcessMessage` does a bit of processing and then *sends a message to another application*... The order in which these messages arrive at the other application is important.

Now, if messages are arriving very rapidly, my concern is that the order in which the created tasks finish will not be the same as the order in which they were created.

I need to ensure that the tasks are created in the order that messages arrive
and that they forward the message in the same order.

(Yes, I am aware that UDP does not guarantee the message arrive in the same order that they were sent, but forget about that ;))

Form what it sounds like, I think I need to wait until the previous task is complete, before marking the current one as complete... I do not want to wait for the previous task to complete before starting the current task.

I hope this makes sense!

**Update based on comments**

Well, I initially did have a loop, created by a task, which constantly checked the message queue and if an item was available, dequeued and processed it:

```
var ProcessMessageQueueLoop = new TaskFactory().StartNew(ProcessMessageQueueThread);

private static void ProcessMessageQueueThread()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (MessageQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            ProcessMessage();
        }
    }
}

private static void OnMessageReceived(object sender, UDPMessage message)
{
        MessageQueue.Enqueue(message);
}
```

I was not sure if this is correct, so I played around a bit, hence my question.

Comment: Why don't you use one of the static helpers such as `Task.Run(...)` ?

Comment: Making sure the tasks finish in the order that the packets arrive seems irrelevant if you're receiving udp packets that could be out of order themselves. I know you say to "ignore it" but, what's the point in trying to order them? Having said that, you probably want just one background thread that processes the messages in a loop and picks up new messages off of the queue.

Comment: Also, unless ProcessMessage processes each message in exactly the same time as all other messages, it could queue messages in a different order from the order of the messages it is processing.  If you absolutely need to produce messages in a specific order, you need to not process messages asynchronously.

Comment: The code in your update seems perfectly fine. As a side note you might want to experiment with ConcurrentQueue vs Queue (both are thread safe), I believe ConcurrentQueue should be faster where there is one thread adding and one removing. Doesn't matter much but could be an interesting experiment if performance is critical.

Comment: @Blam Thank you for your help! I have just tried `ConcurrentQueue` and yes, it is faster by about 2ms ;) Quite significant!

Comment: [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html) so I highly recommend reading the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the update is the correct code for what you want to achieve, which is processing the data in order while not blocking the receiving thread.

Comment: Of course you can.  There's lots of tools in place for this; the simplest being having each be a continuation of the previous one.

Comment: Then it's not asynchronous is it?

Comment: Besides that's exactly what the code in the update does, which I said is the correct way of handling this.

Comment: Of course it is.  It's not doing work in parallel, but it's still asynchronous.

Comment: Creating a dedicated worker thread is different from creating asynchronous operations that simply use some synchronization mechanism to ensure they don't run in parallel.  It might work for him, but it's not the same thing.

Comment: My definition of asynchronous might be slightly wrong so I'll edit the post to reflect that. What is the benefit of running multiple tasks that are synchronised over a single background thread?

Comment: If there is no work being done, there is no thread sitting there doing nothing.  Additionally, the work to be done may not be CPU bound work, it might be a network request, file IO, waiting for a period of time, etc.

Comment: That makes sense, hadn't thought about that, thanks. I'd probably just have this thread start up and shut down as needed if the busy loop ever became an issue. Getting back on track, in this situation I'm happy to say my answer is still "correct" as the OP probably wouldn't want to create a thread for each new message inbound.

Comment: No, your answer is not "correct".  Your answer is very wrong.  Using another thread may well be suitable for the OP, but saying that a proper asynchronous solution isn't is simply wrong.  Very, very wrong.  Additionally, there'd be no need to create a new thread for every request, nor is that what's happening.  The thread pool is being used.